# CPU spiking in Win2003 server with High NDM activity

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, cpu-usage

We have a Win2003 server, where we receive files through NDM and at any time, we would be receiving 6 files from different sources. The CPU on this server is always > 95%, which causes all the componenets to slow down and the server is hung once in every 2 days. We have the latest McAfee running on the server. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it's Connect:Direct you're using or is it an older version or is it the Java-based Connect:Direct Select?

What's the machine (be as detailed as possible, including drives/controller, exact OS version, transport mechanism, hardware - everything really)?
What steps have you already taken to diagnose this problem? What does perfmon say?

Come back to us with this information and we will be able to help more.